# Attach additional files to python streamming job in hadoop

Tags: python, hadoop, amazon-web-services, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I want to run a mapreduce job on ec2.

I have a mapper.py reducer.py and helper.py and a package.

Basically my mapper.py will call helper.py and helper.py will import from for the modules in the package(which are a bunch of python files).

How should my command be when I run the hadoop job?

should I use `-file`, or `-cache`? I tried both, but they dont work.

this is the input I am using:
`hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-0.20.2-cdh3u5.jar -D mapred.map.tasks=2 -D mapred.reduce.tasks=2 -file /root/mapper.py -mapper /root/mapper.py -reducer org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityReducer -input /user/root/Data/data -output /user/root/Data/out -file /root/helper.py`

Comment: AFAIK, stackoverflow is not an official support resource for EC2. Have you tried their official [support channels](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/) or [forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/index.jspa)?

Comment: yes, there is no info about it

Comment: I'm sure Amazon pays someone there to answer questions like yours, have you asked at their support forum? Try there [before asking here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: Can you post the exact command you are using as well as the error message?

Comment: `hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-0.20.2-cdh3u5.jar -D mapred.map.tasks=2 -D mapred.reduce.tasks=2 -file /root/mapper.py -mapper /root/mapper.py -reducer org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityReducer -input /user/root/Data/data -output /user/root/Data/out -file /root/helper.py`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run hadoop streaming on an EC2 instance using additional files by including all the file names in a "-files" param, separated by commas:

```
 bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0.jar -files /home/ec2-user/hadoop-2.6.0/script/mapper.php,/home/ec2-user/hadoop-2.6.0/script/reducer.php,/home/ec2-user/hadoop-2.6.0/script/hadoopconnect.php -input input/* -output output -mapper "php mapper.php" -reducer "php reducer.php"
```